# What log values are available behind an Nginx that passes through 443 traffic

Tags: nginx, ssl, logging

I have an Nginx server accepting 443 traffic and forwarding that traffic unchanged to another Nginx server that acts as the SSL termination point.

I expected to get the IP address of the original client (for logging) via the $realip_remote_addr value - but no such luck.  Same with X-Real-IP and X-Forwarded-For headers.

Is there a process or some other value that I can make available to my SSL termination server to keep my logs better?

Here is the Nginx "router" config:

```
stream {


    log_format  short  '$remote_addr - $realip_remote_addr - [$time_local] '
                  '$status ';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log short;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
        alpha.example.com alpha_backend;
        beta.example.com  beta_backend;
    }

    upstream alpha_backend {
        server 192.168.11.203:443;
    }

    upstream beta_backend {
        server 192.168.11.201:443;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $name;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

Here is the Nginx config for the SSL-terminating server:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/alpha.example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name alpha.example.com www.alpha.example.com;

   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/alpha.example.com/privkey.pem;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/alpha.example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/alpha.example.com/cert.pem;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {

    if ($host = alpha.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name alpha.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The conditions that I am working under are that the two SSL-terminating servers (alpha and beta) must sit behind a single IP address, be separate servers with separate logs.

I have read docs on the "stream" context.  The "short" log_format is a result of trimming out variables that Nginx reported as errors when they were included. If I could pass through either the $remote_addr or the $realip_remote_addr from the "router" server to alpha and beta, I'd be a happy guy.  Other values would be gravy.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/)? Can you share your configuration?

Comment: If your so-called "router" server does not get the real IP address, then you need to look at whatever is in front of it.

Comment: The router server gets the original client IP address.  I'm looking for a way to pass that value on to the SSL terminating servers.

Comment: @Tim The documentation you link to requires a proxy_set_header directive.  I cannot find any location in the stream context that accepts a proxy_set_header statement.